# Geth/Remix Error: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction.How to solve this issue?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, remix, contract-deployment

I have tried to deploy the example given in the following link(using remix and geth).While deploying, an error occurred in both geth and remix. And I found that the usage of "require" causes the problem.How to solve this issue without removing the "require"?

[Smart contract Example](https://www.codementor.io/rogargon/exercise-simple-solidity-smart-contract-for-ethereum-blockchain-m736khtby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require(msg.value == 30 ether, "30 ether initial funding required");`

Base on the code for the constructor you need to transfer 30 ethers to the contract upon deployment.

Comment: Thank you. Successfully deployed the code in Remix.But I don't know how to transfer the value while deploying contract in geth.

Comment: How do you deploy your contract?

Comment: `var gasAmt = eth.estimateGas({data:bin})`  throws gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction in geth